# Pandas Pivot a Column and Fill with Another Pivoted Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a df:

```
id    step    step_description    stepA    stepA_description    date
1     1       Start               1        Beginning            8/6/2017
1     2       Continue            2        Middle               8/7/2017
1     3       Finish              3        End                  8/7/2017
```

I want to pivot this data so it looks like this:

```
id    step1  step2    step3   stepA1    stepA2  stepA3  step1_date  step2_date  step3_date
1     Start  Continue Finish  Beginning Middle  End     8/6/2017    8/7/2017    8/7/2017
```

This means the the step column has to be pivoted and then filled with another pivoted column. Is there a way to accomplish this with Pandas? I have read the docs for the pivot options (and have used several of the options for more straightforward cases in the past), but I couldn't decipher a way to accomplish this.

I can use pivot table to get a multi-level index that has the structure I want. Is there a way to essentially "drop" the index down so that the bottom of the hierarchy becomes the values of the df?

Thank you for any insight you all might have!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 2 solutions - use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='id', columns='step', values='step_description').add_prefix('step')
print (df1)
step  step1     step2   step3
id                           
1     Start  Continue  Finish
```

---

```
df1 = df.set_index(['id', 'step'])['step_description'].unstack().add_prefix('step')
print (df1)
step  step1     step2   step3
id                           
1     Start  Continue  Finish
```

But if duplicates, need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) or aggregate with `groupby` and `apply` join:

```
print (df)
  id  step step_description
0   1     1            Start<-Same id=1, step=1
1   1     1           Start1<-Same id=1, step=1
2   1     2         Continue
3   1     3           Finish

df2=df.pivot_table(index='id', 
                   columns='step', 
                   values='step_description',
                   aggfunc=', '.join).add_prefix('step')
print (df2)
step          step1     step2   step3
id                                   
1     Start, Start1  Continue  Finish
```

---

```
df2=df.groupby(['id', 'step'])['step_description'].apply(','.join)
                                                  .unstack().add_prefix('step')
print (df2)
step         step1     step2   step3
id                                  
1     Start,Start1  Continue  Finish
```

EDIT:

You need 2 `DataFrame`s and then `concat` them:

```
cols = ['id','step','step_description','date']
df1 = df[cols].set_index(['id', 'step']).unstack().rename(columns={'step_description':'des'})
df1.columns = ['step{}_{}'.format(x[1], x[0]) for x in df1.columns]
print (df1)
   step1_des step2_des step3_des step1_date step2_date step3_date
id                                                               
1      Start  Continue    Finish   8/6/2017   8/7/2017   8/7/2017

df2 = df.set_index(['id', 'stepA'])['stepA_description'].unstack().add_prefix('stepA')
print (df2)
stepA     stepA1  stepA2 stepA3
id                             
1      Beginning  Middle    End

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   id step1_des step2_des step3_des step1_date step2_date step3_date  \
0   1     Start  Continue    Finish   8/6/2017   8/7/2017   8/7/2017   

      stepA1  stepA2 stepA3  
0  Beginning  Middle    End
```

Comment: Thank you! The first line works perfectly - setting the index causes a key error on `id`. Also, it's not possible to do a multiple field index. I know that's not what I asked for!

Comment: Thank you, again. The pivot table method allows for multi-field index as well. How difficult do you think it would be to incorporate another two columns into the mix? For example, if I added `step_2` and `step_description_2` that needed another three columns added to the pivot table? Or would it be simpler to do each pivot separately and join the dfs back together?

Comment: Give me some time.

Comment: There are always numbers? How many pairs step with description is in real data?

Comment: Four (number, description) pairs. Plus the initial `step` field needs multiple fields to fill it. So it needs three columns filled by the `step_description`, but it also needs three columns filled by the `step_date`.

Comment: Can you add 2 new columns to sample data? because there is no `number` column.

Comment: Sorry, it was really complicated, check edited answer.

Comment: Don't apologize - thank you very much! That's why I came here - it was too complicated for my novice brain.

Comment: How would duplicates be handled with the new solution?

Comment: You can use `df1=df.pivot_table(index='id', 
                   columns='step', 
                   values=['step_description','date']
                   aggfunc=', '.join)
print (df1)` and second df is `df2=df.pivot_table(index='id', 
                   columns='step'A, 
                   values='stepA_description',
                   aggfunc=', '.join).add_prefix('stepA')
print (df2)`. Sorry. I am on phone only.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `pivot` and `set_index` methods, you can also use `groupby`

```
df.groupby(['id', 'step'])['step_description'].sum().unstack().add_prefix('step'
```

Comment: Thank you, John! Do you know of a way to allow for a multiple field index with this method? For example, if there's another field called `id2` that is the same for all records as well.